# How to merge all commits from one branch to another?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-merge, branching-and-merging

I want to merge branch A to master but when I use "git merge A" on master it will merge the branches but will only record one commit on master where as I commited like 20 on branch A. I would like to merge all the commits from A to master. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have cross-tagged this as both [git](/questions/tagged/git) and [[image]github](/questions/tagged/github), and the answers are different for these two different situations.

GitHub offers a single button labeled "Merge pull request", with a dropdown triangle.  Clicking on the triangle offers more options (at least normally—[the GitHub help page](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request/) says that this "Depend[s] on the merge options enabled for your repository"):

- Create a merge commit
- Squash and merge
- Rebase and merge

The Git command line is different, being simultaneously simpler and more complicated.  You can run any of these commands:

- `git merge` to get a default action that is situation-dependent;
- `git merge --ff-only` to prevent merging, but allow a fast-forward action;
- `git merge --squash` to force a squash action, without creating a merge;
- `git merge --no-ff` to force a merge action; or
- `git rebase` followed by `git merge --ff-only` to copy the commits such that fast-forwarding is possible—this is the default rebase action—and then to do a fast-forward action.

The first of the three GitHub actions, "Create a merge commit", is equivalent to the command-line `git merge --no-ff`, in terms of final result (the difference is that GitHub won't offer this option at all if there are merge conflicts, but [see this page](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-on-github/) as well).  The second of the three GitHub actions is equivalent to the command-line `git merge --squash` and is what you described in your question:

> ... will only record one commit on master where as I committed like 20 on branch A

Note that the new commit has the same *effect* as the other N commits, but is an ordinary, non-merge, single-parent commit (this is hard to see in the GitHub interface as it tries to hide the nonlinear nature of Git commit graphs).  See [this GitHub help page squash diagram](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-request-merges/#squash-and-merge-your-pull-request-commits).  (Note that the plain-merge diagram on that page is rather poor, but the squash one is decent.)  A real merge, made with `--no-ff` on the command line, has *two* parents: the first parent is the previous commit on the branch on which you performed the merge (i.e., `master`), and the second parent is the tip commit of the branch that was merged (branch `A` in your example).  This means that all N separate commits remain separate: there is just one new commit added that represents the result of *combining* those separate commits.

In many ways, this is the best result: it allows you to view the feature addition as a single unit (the merge commit), or as a series of changes (the N separate commits on the side branch).  But it does make for a more tangled history: if the fact that there was a merge is expected to be useless or distracting in the future, while the N separate commits are expected to be useful (for debugging, for instance), it may be better to use a *fast-forward* operation.

As I mentioned above, a fast-forward is not a merge at all.  However, fast-forward is only possible if all the "new" commits to be merged are "ahead of" all the current commits.  Visualizing whether this is the case is, as far as I can tell, impossible<sup>1</sup> on GitHub.

If fast-forward *is* possible, the command-line command `git merge` will do it by default.  If it's possible, `git merge --ff-only` will succeed.  So if you want to attempt a fast-forward, but *not* create an actual merge commit if it's *not* possible, you can simply use `git merge --ff-only` and observe whether it succeeds or fails.

If a fast-forward is currently *not* possible, you can use `git rebase` to make it become possible, after which you can use `git merge` (optionally with `--ff-only`, either as a safety check, or to override any configuration you set with `git config merge.ff`).  Rebasing is somewhat complex, at least when it goes wrong, so as others said you should read up on it first.

---

<sup>1</sup>Or at least, too difficult to bother.  If there's a clicky button that shows the actual commit graph, that might be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like rebasing into master is what you're looking for.

Try:

```
git checkout A
git rebase master
```

I suggest that you read about the difference between merging and rebasing here https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing